# Parse date format as mm-yy from mm/yy

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I wanna convert `MM/YY` formatted string date to mm-yy DateTime. And set as the value for rad masked edit box. But it returns to me

> "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

I tried with

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("11/17", "MMyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

for eg, I want to convert `03/16` and set value of radmasked edit box masked as `MMyy` as `03-16`

Comment: _"convert MM/YY formatted string date to mm-yy DateTime"_ A DateTime has no format, so you wana convert a string to DateTime and this to a formatted string?

Comment: Why not `Replace`? `string result = "11/17".Replace('/', '-');`

Comment: I had tried that but masked edit box does accept that value
radMebDate.Value = someDto.date;
for someDto.date value is3-17 but radMebDate.Value is 04-18

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why do you expect this to work at all?

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("11/17", "MMyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You get a string `11/17` and try to parse it with a format that doesn't contain any delimiters.

This works:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("11/17", "MM/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If you want to convert it to a string with this format: `MMyy`:

```
string result = dt.ToString("MMyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Since it's not clear, if you want this instead: `MM-yy`

```
 string result = dt.ToString("MM-yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

> It's working for 11/17,12/17. but not in the case of 3/12 etc i.e when
>   a month is a single digit.

You haven't mentioned that it's possible that the month has a single digit, however:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("3/17", "M/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: It's working for 11/17,12/17. but not in the case of 3/12 etc i.e when a month is a single digit.

Comment: @ajit: then use `DateTime.ParseExact("3/17", "M/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: Date may have single digit month or else, how can i use in both case

Comment: @ajit my approach works for both

Comment: Yeah It worked thanks

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("11/17", "MM/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Then you can convert it to your desired format

```
string formattedDate = dt.ToString("MM-yy");
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to change delimeter `'/'` into `'-'` *only*, i.e. if you have no need in `DateTime` *temporary value*, you can just `Replace`:

```
    string source = "11/17";

    // 11-17: changing '/' to '-'
    string result = source.Replace('/', '-');
```